# Division with decimals below zero vb.net

Tags: vb.net, division, modulus

I'm writing a program in vb.net which allows the user to input an amount of money and then outputs the minimum number of coins that are needed to make that amount. For example if the user inputs £3.43 the program would output 1 x £2, 1x £1, 2x £20p, 1x 2p and 1x 1p.

I have the program working for one and two pound coins but as soon as the program checks for smaller coins (E.G. below £1) the program doesn't recognize anything. The program uses division and modulus to do this, for each coin it divides the amount by the value of the coin (ignoring the remainder), sets the value of a variable named "remainder" as the amount modulus by the value of the coin and resets the amount to the value of the remainder

The code is below:

```
Public Class MinimumCoins
Dim ammount As Decimal
Dim TwoPound As Integer
Dim OnePound As Integer
Dim fifty As Integer
Dim twenty As Integer
Dim ten As Integer
Dim five As Integer
Dim two As Integer
Dim one As Integer
Dim remainder As Decimal

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    ammount = InputBox("Enter Ammount")

    TwoPound = ammount \ 2
    remainder = ammount Mod 2
    ammount = remainder

    OnePound = ammount \ 1
    remainder = ammount Mod 1
    ammount = remainder

    remainder = remainder * 100

    fifty = ammount \ 50
    remainder = ammount Mod 50
    ammount = remainder

    twenty = ammount \ 20
    remainder = ammount Mod 20
    ammount = remainder

    ten = ammount \ 10
    remainder = ammount Mod 10
    ammount = remainder

    five = ammount \ 5
    remainder = ammount Mod 5
    ammount = remainder

    two = ammount \ 2
    remainder = ammount Mod 2
    ammount = remainder

    one = ammount \ 1

    lblOutput.Text = TwoPound & " X" & " £2.00" & vbNewLine & OnePound & " X" & " £1.00" & vbNewLine & fifty & "X" & " 50p" & vbNewLine & twenty & " X" & " 20p" & vbNewLine & ten & " X" & " 10p" & vbNewLine & five & " X" & " 5p" & vbNewLine & two & " X" & " 2p" & vbNewLine & one & " X" & " 1p"



End Sub
End Class
```

The first two times the program is run (for one pound and two pound coins) it works perfectly fine but then the program displays no coins are needed for any amount smaller than £1.

Comment: It is time to take a break and sleep on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your `ammount` to the remainder of the `Mod 1` (so for an input of 2.53, your `ammount` is now 0.53)

Then you multiply remainder by 100 and store it back into `remainder`, so remainder is `53`, `ammount` is still `0.53`..

And then you carry on doing maths on the `ammount` of 0.53, so your program is going to be asking these questions:

- "How many times does 50p go into 0.53p?" 0
- "How many times does 20p go into 0.53p?" 0
- "How many times does 10p go into 0.53p?" 0
- And so on..

I haven't given you the exact answer to your problem, but there's enough in here to work it out - it'll be a better learning exercise for you if you think that last part through yourself, rather than me just giving you the answer directly :)

Good luck

Comment: As well as multiplying the remainder variable by 100 I've also multiplied the amount variable by 100 meaning the result is now correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: (The operation to multiply the remainder by 100 is what we call a non-op; it doesn't do anything, the result isn't used and it is soon overwritten by another operation) You deduced the correct answer; the line `remainder = remainder * 100` should be `ammount = remainder * 100`, and the `ammount=remainder` line above it should be removed. By way of a tip for future programming in an academic context, you would be well served by writing out the entire logic of your program in 'comments first, then translating it into code. This is because you think in (English), not code...

Comment: ..trying to think and translate in one step seldom ends well. Even as a highly experienced developer, I still write complex algorithms out in comment form first, using high level natural language. Then i translate into code. I do the same when speaking a foreign language; arrange the sentence in English, then convert it to French, then speak it. It takes a long time to become fluent to the point that you think in a non-native language. Coding is no different, so comment first, and code by conversion later. You'd have likely avoided this bug if the algorithm was written out in English first :)